# Moto 360 Deploying from Android Studio extremely slow

Tags: android, deployment, adb, wear-os, moto-360

Trying to run a wear counterpart of an Android app directly on Moto 360, after having it connected and listed as a target device.

ADB can see it and communicates fine.

However, the deployment message is not progressing for a long time, about 10 mins.

Eventually, the app gets installed, but this makes continuous development on the device almost impossible.

Is there any way to speed up this installation? I really doubt that the Bluetooth link is that slow.

Comment: mine is slow too but it certainly does not take 10 mins to install on the device; maybe a minute. you could try signing your apk for release and have it install itself

Comment: Thanks - tried that before, the adb install hangs the same way. Which speed does it give to you after installation?

Comment: adb debugging is really slow when stepping through code, it take like a minute just to get to the next line. installing right from a signed apk is pretty quick though

Comment: How big is the APK you are pushing to the wearable?

Comment: same here, a minute only with a "hello world" apk

Comment: Same here. It's so incredibly slow. I just put some buttons on the wear app so it's not even that big. It's a pretty basic apk.

Comment: Seems this is because of bluetooth speed.

Comment: Take a look at this Moto 360 hack ; http://www.rootjunky.com/moto-360-adapter-usb-cable/ - For any serious development with functionality that can not be tested through emulator.... The bluetooth transfer is just not feasable for development... I am afraid.

Comment: The Install time is slow as well by the way. Faster transfer won't help that.

Comment: help! :-) Development is pretty impossible at this stage without a fix for this...

Comment: I am also facing the same issue :( Will running on emulator help here since the data transfer is not on bluetooth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and started using Emulator.
Emulator is pretty fast since there is not data transfer over bluetooth.

To setup an emulator, you can use the following tutorials.
http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/how-to-create-a-custom-android-wear-watch-face/120
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html

The next update of android wear is coming up with Wi-fi. With that we should be able to deploy it in Wi-fi itself.

http://androidcommunity.com/moto-360-getting-wifi-support-after-android-wear-update-20150421/

Answer (score 3):

Well sometimes you don't really have the option of using an emulator.

My experiences with deploying direct on the device is pretty much the same as yours.

For me, the initial deployments were quick but eventually they began to slow down after a few redeployments

What worked for me was this:

1. Install TaskManager on the wear (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rocketstartups.weartaskmanager&hl=en)
2. Before a deploy, open Task Manager on the wear and "close all" apps.
3. Now deploy. I get consistent deployments within a minute.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I've had this trouble on both of my Android Wear watches (a Moto 360 and and LG G Watch - thank you I/O). I've sometimes found it helps to disable, then re-enable, **ADB debugging** in the **Developer options** on-device. I have no explanation for why this would make a difference, but in my experience, it can - YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I have the process down to about two minutes (a godsend considering the previous 10+ minute times) using the following procedure with Android Studio:

1 - Make sure your watch is well charged.

2 - Download and install the task manager app as recommended by allkenang

3 - Delete current version of application; 
adb -s localhost:4444 uninstall com.example.packagename (or 127.0.0.1:4444 if you are using that) - if this says -waiting for device- it usually won't work and you will need to disconnect and reconnect the watch. You should get a 'success' message after a second or two.

4 - Install new version of your application to your watch as normal.

5 - When you see the text "DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r ...", close all apps using the task manager. Repeat this every 3 seconds.

Not sure if any of these steps are unnecessary, but that's the process I use and its resolving the problem.